# problems with run ProcessDialog in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I use a processDialog while creating a charts, the processDialog appears but dont spin. I searched and I need use Async Task, but I dont have where I have to put the code:

This is my code:

```
bCrearGraf2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                startProgressDialog(v);
                irGraficaComparativa(null);


                }
        });
```

startProgressDialog() is this:

```
public void startProgressDialog(View V)
              {
               progressBar = new ProgressDialog(V.getContext());
               progressBar.setCancelable(true);
               progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
               progressBar.setMessage("Creating chart");
               progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

               progressBar.show();

              }
```

irGraficaComparativa() start the new activity:

```
public void irGraficaComparativa(View view){

    Intent i =new Intent(this,Graficas_comparativa.class);
    i.putExtra("Id_vehiculo1",idVehChar1);
    i.putExtra("Nomb_vehiculo1",nombVeh1);
    i.putExtra("Id_vehiculo2",idVehChar2);
    i.putExtra("Nomb_vehiculo2",nombVeh2);

    Log.d("Veh1","Nombre: " + nombVeh1 + " ID: " + idVehChar1);
    Log.d("Veh1","Nombre: " + nombVeh2 + " ID: " + idVehChar2);

    startActivity(i);

}
```

Into the activity I create a AsyncTask class, but I dont know where put the code. 
This the AsyncTask class:

```
public class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,Void>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        progressBar.dismiss();
    }


}
```

thanks a lot.

Comment: Put the progress dialog showing code in onPreExecute() method
and dismissal code in onPostExecute(Void result) method

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
public class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,Void>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        startProgressDialog(v);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
   {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
    {
        progressBar.dismiss();
        irGraficaComparativa(null);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your comment, finally I search this tuto, when you can custom a animation   http://karanbalkar.com/2012/10/tutorial-5-custom-progressdialog-with-asynctask/

Answer (score 0):

> In here the progress bar is useless so try below link[Progress bar in android](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-progress-bar-example/)

Comment: thanks for the link, but I need use  STYLE_SPINNER because I dont know how much time expend.